# Clojure precondition with local variable

Tags: optimization, clojure, let, preconditions

Is there any way to store the result of a computation performed in a precondition so that it can be used in the actual function body.

This is awful (costly-computation runs twice):

```
(defn bar [x]                                                                           
  {:pre [(> (costly-computation x) 1337)]}                                                
  (costly-computation x))
```

I would like to do something along these lines. But this doesn't work.

```
(defn smartbar [x]
  (let [res (costly-computation x)]                                                       
    {:pre [(> res 1337)]}
    res))
```

Comment: Does it look more like a :post condition?

Comment: A post condition should work. Also, you can simply use `assert` to force an error if your condition is not met.

Comment: It's a contrived example. I need to check the condition before executing the bulk of the function body. Post condition is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple ways to tackle this.  For example you can compute **(costly-computation x)** outside of (bar) function and pass it as a parameter to (bar) function.

Or you can compute **(costly-computation x)** inside (bar) function and validate there, no {:pre} condition.

Or write a Macro to do exactly what you want!

Your smartbar isn't going to work because that isn't how defn macro is created to do.
Try this inside the REPL:

```
(source defn)
```